# Low FPS on dota. How to fix?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, games, steam, gpu-driver

recently just installed 14.04. I m new in ubuntu. I installed steam and dota 2. I have intel i5 core 4200, 16 gb ram, Intel HD 4600.
 In Windows 10, it was 80-100 FPS. 
But in ubuntu, 25-40 fps. What is the problem? All drivers upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

If all drivers and kernels are updated, then install `indicator-cpufreq` and `reboot`, and then put your CPU frequency at PERFORMANCE. Hope it helps.

Comment: This solution was found on Steam Community Forum http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864976115271001635/   :)